# How can the Google Chrome DevTools Console be made fullscreen using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console, fullscreen, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering whether it is possible to make the [Google Chrome DevTools Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) go fullscreen using JavaScript?

Comment: you didn't mean, the "undock into a separate window"-button on the top right of the console window?

Comment: @Thomas yeah , and then make it full screen programatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Google Chrome console doesn't include any Javascript API's for making the window full screen (or for modifying window dimensions at all). Unfortunately, this means it is not currently possible to natively alter the size of the console (or make it go full screen) programatically.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference

---

That said, Chrome dev tools is built to be extensible and anything is *possible*. If you wish to create your own Chrome plugin to interact with the console window and make it full screen programatically, you very likely can.

The obvious downside to this method is that you'd have to ask a user to install your custom plugin in order to use this functionality. That may not pose a problem depending on your use-case, but it's something to be aware of.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating

Comment: i didn't get it , how come  altering the size of the console can be related to a huge number of security implications ? Can you explain it  with more details ?

Comment: Of course. Making anything full screen programatically (as in, without letting the user know or asking for permission) means that you are essentially taking control of their _entire_ screen against their will/konwledge. Now I'm sure that this is not the use you had in mind, but the malicious uses for such functionality are many.

Comment: @manualva That's a fair point; I made a bad answer before I fully understood the site. I've just updated it to remove the potentially misleading information and add a source. Hope this is okay.